# Quick Dynamics Question about Extension Methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, dynamic

Is it possible to apply a Dynamic Variable to an Extension Method?

Sample: pulled from my current project

```
for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++)
{
  for (int e = 0; e < 9; e++) 
  { 
    //                                                         t         e
    projectArray[1, t, e] = projectFromJson.Templates.Template_0.Element_0;
    projectArray[1, t, e] = projectFromJson.Templates.Template_0.Element_0;
    projectArray[1, t, e] = projectFromJson.Templates.Template_0.Element_0;
  }
}
```

Desired Result: I would like to be able to assemble the array with variables from Template_0 through Template_5, and for each of those templates add in the elements Element_0 through Element_10, without having to write 60 lines of almost the exact same thing.

Platform: C# Windows Forms Application, Visual Studio 2019

Comment: what's that got to do with dynamic variables or extension methods? but what you _want_ to do is have a look at reflection to access properties based on their name.

Comment: The debug squiggles out the "Template_0" and or "Element_0" when I try to use a variable in it and says the "projcectFromJson" does not contain an definition for the variable, and that no "Extension Method" for whatever could be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reflection is ok for you, that you can use something like this

```
    for(var i=0;i<templatesCount;i++)
    {
        var propInfo =projectFromJson.Templates.GetType().GetProperty("Template_"+i);
        var template = propInfo.GetValue(projectFromJson.Templates);
    
        for(var j=0;j<elementsCount;j++)
        {
            var elemPropInfo = template.GetType().GetProperty("Element_" + j);
            var elem = elemPropInfo.GetValue(template);
    
            projectArray[1, i, j] = elem;
        }
    }
```

And of course you can create extension method, which will use such a technique.

Disclaimer: it's just a concept, I did not actually tested this.

Comment: What would this process be called so I can do some research on it, is it just called reflection?

Comment: The technique is actually called reflection. You can find main concepts in a documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it out and see if this will do what i need, Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I reviewed Serg's response and though it is just a concept by Serg, it actually works perfectly where I need it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below sample console code. You can get template and element from loop and get it in required format

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int t = 0; t <= 5; t++)
            {
                for (int e = 0; e <= 9; e++)
                {
                    //                                                         t         e
                    Console.WriteLine("First Template t:" + t + "Second Template e:"+e);
                
                }
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```